# page redirect not happening on click of <a> link. X-Frame-Options set to 'DENY'

Tags: php, iframe, redirect, x-frame-options

On a particular page on my website say **example.com/redirect.php** I have written an anchor tag `<a href="http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151">path</a>`.


On click of this link, page is not loaded. While inspecting the element I got this error:

*Refused to display 'https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151' in a frame because it set 
'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'*

After googling I found that this is the intended behaviour as owner of the other website doesn't want to display it's content in an iframe outside of it's domain.

I have tried these, but all of them are loading in iframe.

1. window.location.href = "https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151";
2. `<?php header(location: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151"); ?>`
3. window.location.replace("https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151");

I have two questions:

1. Why on click of **path** link, the new page is loading in an iframe on the same page(**redirect.php**) rather than redirecting to ycombinator's page.
2. How can I make the user to redirect to any page outside of my website.

P.S. I am using lamp stack.

**Update:** As suggested by **Serge Seredenko** in comments, I tried with top.location.href = "..."; This worked for me and I am able to redirect the page.

**Another Problem:** I need the referer's url. After performing redirect using the Serge Seredenko's method I am not getting the actual referer url for $_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER'] instead I am getting internal url. I need the actual referer url.

I tried the server side url redirection using: 
`<?php header(location: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151"); ?>`. 
but I am getting this error: **'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'**.

How can I make server side url redirect and preserve the actual referer url ?.
 Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: You wrote it yourself: if the website doen't want you to load it in frame, then you just can't.

Comment: I don't want the new page to load in an iframe.

Comment: Have you tried top.location.href = "..."?

Comment: http://sh0r.in/redirect.php

Answer (score 0):

1)
Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

2) Try this:

```php
<?php
//...some your code
print '<script type="text/javascript"> location.replace("https://google.com/"); </script>';
//...
?>
```

Comment: Not working. In console I got this error, Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=wnrAVvOXBenA8geQxLjQAg&gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: Ok, please cheak your webserver configuration.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: This page shows how you can configure your web server to send  X-Frame-Options in header. I don't want to send  X-Frame-Options. I just want a redirect.

Comment: Checked, it works for me. Try:

<?php
header("Location: $url");
?>

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get this X-Frame-Options error the browser is expecting to receive a 'partial' HTML page. Not a complete HTML page with  tags etc.

This means that when the browser does the request to the server.
For eg if Both screens are in 'Transition mode' `(Source and destination for example in same page but in different tab like this situation)`. We get same error.